# JSP to Facelets equivalent for database provided URL linking in loop

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

I'm porting the servlet/jsp Netbeans' Affableben tutorial to JSF Framework, and want to use Facelets for the view.

I already have the JPA entities, the session beans and the managed beans. I'm starting with the View. However, I have not found the equivalent in Facelets to work around this line:

```
<a href="<c:url value='category?${category.id}'/>">
```

This is the full loop, both in jsp and facelets:

JSP code:

```
<c:forEach var="category" items="${categories}">
    <div class="categoryBox">
        <a href="<c:url value='category?${category.id}'/>">
            <span class="categoryLabel"></span>
            <span class="categoryLabelText"><fmt:message key='${category.name}'/></span>

            <img src="${initParam.categoryImagePath}${category.name}.jpg"
                 alt="<fmt:message key='${category.name}'/>" class="categoryImage">
        </a>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Equivalent Facelets code:

```
<ui:repeat var="category" value="${categoryController.items}">
    <div class="categoryBox">
        <h:link outcome="${category.id}"/>
        <span class="categoryLabel"></span>
        <span class="categoryLabelText">${category.name}</span>

        <img src="./resources/img/categories/${category.name}.jpg"
                 alt="${category.name}" class="categoryImage"/>

    </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

This line is not working in Facelets as expected:

```
<h:link outcome="${category.id}"/>
```

What would be a working equivalent in Facelets?

EDIT 1

```
public String getName() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");
}
```

Warning message: Unable to find resource img/categories/fruit+%26+veg.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<h:link>` utilizes JSF implicit navigation and requires a real (implicit) navigation outcome value. You need to specify the view ID in the outcome. You need to specify request parameters by `<f:param>`. You also need to nest the spans and the image in the link as you did in your initial example. Assuming that you have a `category.xhtml` file in the root, this should do:

```
<h:link outcome="category">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{category.id}" />

    <span class="categoryLabel"></span>
    <span class="categoryLabelText">#{category.name}</span>
    <img src="./resources/img/categories/#{category.name}.jpg"
             alt="#{category.name}" class="categoryImage"/>
</h:link>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, you should be using `<h:graphicImage>` instead of `<img>` as well. This way JSF will ensure that the `src` is properly set. In your particular case that would be

```
<h:graphicImage name="img/categories/#{category.name}.jpg"
    alt="#{category.name}" class="categoryImage"/>
```

*(note that I replaced `${}` by `#{}`, just to adhere the standard and for the consistency)*

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, it helped me a lot. Just a question: What is the Facelets equivalent or work around for <:choose> ? (if this is not related, I will post a new thread, just tell me)

Comment: Ah, I forgot. Using <h:graphicImage> instead of <img> causes an image not being rendered if its name string has been fetched from database and its field value has an ampersand or spaces, like for example 'fruit & veg'.

Comment: 1) Use `rendered` attribute of the JSF component. 2) You should not have invalid characters in URLs. Use `URLEncoder`.

Comment: `String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(raw, "UTF-8");`. Use this `encoded` value in URL.

Comment: I imported the needed libraries and edited the category entity class and added a bit of code in the name getter method. It doesn't show the image. See EDIT 1 in initial thread above.

Comment: Interesting. The `+` inside the URI fails while it works fine inside the query string. You'd need to replace it by `%20` afterwards. I.e. `return URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20");`

Comment: Adding .replace("+", "%20") will fire this warning message: Unable to find resource img/categories/fruit%20%26%20veg.jpg

Comment: So it seems that without URLEncoder the applicattion does find the resource file, but the browser?? cannot render it properly. However, implementing URLEncoder, the application is unable to find the resource file in the first place. I guess the URLencoding must be implemented AFTER the application loads the resource file. But... how to do this?

Comment: Use `<img>` instead of `<h:graphicImage>`. This is indeed pretty nasty, but, on the other hand, having illegal characters in filenames for URL resources is also nasty. Can't you just edit those filenames?

Comment: Yes, I can edit those filenames. Thank you for your answers. I learned about URLEncoding, which I had no idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change from this line:

```
<a href="<c:url value='category?${category.id}'/>">
```

to this:

```
<h:link outcome="category.xhtml?id=#{category.id}" />
<h:link outcome="category">
   <f:param name="id" value="#{category.id}" />
</h:link>
<h:outputLink value="category.xhtml?id=#{category.id}" ></h:outputLink>
```